# Time Series Analysis for Individual Customers

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, forecasting, arima

I a time series data for 1000 customers regarding the number of purchases they made in the last 2 years. I am able to build the time series forecasting model for the entire dataset. But now I want to build the forecasting model for the each of the 1000 customers, what is the best approach to solve this problem.

PS: One method I can think of is iterating over each of the 1000 customer and built the separate model for each of them. But in long run its not going to be feasible solution

Can someone help me with the better approach

sample data:

```
custmore_id,date,count_order
1,2015-06,24
1,2015-07,26
...
1,2017-08,320
2,2015-06,12
2,2015-07,32
..
2,2017-08,500
```

Comment: Have you tried to get all customers using group_by, then applied your time series forecasting model for each child dataframe whose customer='Customer 1 or 2 etc'?

Comment: Yes I did that. But its not that efficient , Plus I have to modify the parameters for each timeseries

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking for?  Are you looking for a way to organize the data in a specific fashion or a suggestion for a generalized model (a question better suited to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com))?

Comment: I am asking for an approach to design a generic model

Answer (score 0):

First , create a function
`def Forecast(costumer_id,prediction_date):
     df_customer = df[df['customer_id']==customer_id]
     do forecasting on df_customer
     return forecast for customer and prediction_date`
then use the Pool method of multiprocess library to parallel process the customers:

`pool.map(Forecast,np.unique(df['customer_id']))`
and finally concat the results

Comment: I have implemented something similar but didn't try multiprocessing approach. Will try that now